# PDF - Are Bookmarks and Hyperlinks equivalent?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, bookmarks

Are Bookmarks and Hyperlinks treated the same in PDF documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `bookmark` references a specific page/paragraph/sentence/whatever within the `PDF` itself.

A `hyperlink` in a PDF can reference a `bookmark` (similar to `#anchors` in `HTML`) but can also point to `external resources`.

Comment: This is incorrect.  A bookmark is an element in a tree structure that contains a set of actions to perform when clicked on.  This action mechanism is/may be identical to that which is used in link annotations (there are two different mechanisms, a Destination or an Action).  This is described in section 12.3.3 in the PDF spec (Document Outline), more specifically in table 153 - Dest and A.

Answer (score 3):

No, bookmarks (outlines) and hyperlinks (link annotations) are not equivalent -- but internally they can share some common elements. For example, a bookmark can be used to link to a specific page in a document and so can a hyperlink via Go-To Actions.